# Can my fiancé enter UK more than once on a multiple-entry Standard Visitor visa?

Tags: repeat-visits, standard-visitor-visas

My fiancé was granted a Standard Visitor visa in November and has just returned back to his home country after spending two weeks in the U.K. as stated on the application.

Can he return again for another holiday in a few months or will this be an issue?

Comment: He can come back but the border agent will ask questions anyway and will need to be convinced he isn't trying to be a resident. And if he does this very frequently then there might be trouble at the landing interview.

Comment: Thanks all he has a legitimate reason to return to visit myself and my family again I also have used all my annual leave to visit him

Comment: @Jenna if you're happy with the answers, you should accept your favourite by clicking the "tick" outline next to it.  That drives the local reputation system, and is local etiquette.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is always a risk anyone turning up at a border may be refused entry. A second visit *slightly* more than a first visit (since might be a sign of a visa run) and *slightly* less than a first visit (since now applicant has a track record of having not overstayed, etc).

But a multiple entry visa exists to permit more than one entry so it is almost expected that someone with such will return within the validity period. There is no particular reason to expect any issues but, as usual, no one can guarantee there won't be. With ½ month visit plus ~3 months away there is nothing specific to raise concerns.

"I didn't have time to see all I wanted to when here last" is quite a plausible rationale and will probably be found acceptable if believed.

There has been mention on TSE of a "rule of thumb" for CBP, something like "spend more time out of the country than in or Immigration will be sure to be very interested in one's motives". This is similar to some *official* regulations such as the [90/180 visa rule](https://travel.stackexchange.com/tags/90-180-visa-rules/info). Given the all-round bother of travel (eg costs and time), rather than say `½ month visit plus ~3 months away plus another ½ month visit` a single visit for 1 month instead may make more economic sense, hence there is some implication within `½ month visit plus ~3 months away plus another ½ month visit` of strong ties to 'overseas' - in other words something is 'pulling' the visitor back home (it's usually a job!) and that can reassure the IO that the visitor is not seeking to set up permanent residence in the UK (illegally).

Answer (score 8):

The UK Standard Visitor Visa is a multiple-entry entry clearance that runs for 6 months. During that time the holder can come and go much the same as a non-visa national (e.g., Americans, Canadians, and so on).

The big issue arises when someone's visit pattern implies that there has been a *change of circumstances* since the visa was issued. For example, if someone  claims to be employed full-time (studying full-time, etc) at the application stage and then proceeds to visit for 3 or 4 months at a time or builds up 5 or 6 visits in a short period of time, it raises a flag.  The flag says that the person's visit pattern is out-of-whack with their stated lifestyle.

Immigration Officers are trained to spot those flags and follow up on them. A change of circumstances will get them annoyed because the rules say that the person will declare them. So if there's been a change of circumstances your fiance should always take care to declare it up front.  IO's will also get *critically annoyed* if they think the person misrepresented their lifestyle at the application stage.  This would also be indicated by a person spending lots of time in the UK because people who are employed do not usually do that.

> Can he return again for another holiday in a few months or will this
>   be an issue?

The best rule of thumb is to look carefully at what was portrayed at the application stage.  If nothing has changed and the visit sync's up with the person's lifestyle and circumstances then of course, enjoy another visit (or several visits).  Your fiance would say something like...

> The purpose of my visit is to maintain a relationship and there are no
>   changes in my personal circumstances between now and when my visa was
>   issued.

It needs to be an honest statement.  As always, interaction with a British Immigration Officer is largely governed by personal impact and articulation skills.  Everything (literally *everything*) is in the discretionary zone.

Also I like to advise people arriving on Standard Visitor Visas to have all of the original evidence they used to hand. They should also have accommodation plans to hand. Sometimes it's helpful, sometimes it doesn't matter.

Comment: Thanks a lot and circumstances haven't changed. His father is his boss and knows the importance of our relationship so is always happy to allow the time off

Comment: @Jenna It might help to have a letter from his boss confirming that he is still employed, and the circumstances under which he is given time off work (using standard vacation time, unpaid leave, etc).